# How to inherit color from background of the div instead of the font color

Tags: html, css, inheritance

How can I inherit the background color from the div above instead of the font color? I have a white background so the the :after won't be visible.

```
<div class="drupes">
  <h1>Web-Only</h1>
</div>
```

```
div {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f65e3f;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.drupes:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 140px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
```

Probably I am missing something very simple but I just can't figure it out.

Tried to make the div the parent but it would still take the font color

https://jsfiddle.net/732rc5bh/

Comment: it seems you want to draw a triangle so don't use the border trick but consider clip-path and you can use background: inherit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-left-color: inherit;`: You are not inheriting from background color, but from border color. And default border color is black.

Set parent element border color to match background color

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f65e3f;
  border-color: #f65e3f; /* Added code */
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.drupes:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 140px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="drupes">
  <h1>Web-Only</h1>
</div>
```